# How do I get this button underneath between my two NumberPickers?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, numberpicker

Right now I have two NumberPickers and a Start button, my XML is set up like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.skytbest.intervaltrainer.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Label"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/timer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/numberPickers">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:layout_below="@id/numberPickers"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/colon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Start button to side]

How can I get my Start button to be directly below the two NumberPickers and span the width of the NumberPickers?

If you're wondering about the TextView it is a ":" that you can't really see right now since the Button is offsetting my NumberPickers, but it is in a different layout so that it can be layered over the NumberPickers without spreading them apart. It looks like a clock when it is centered.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making the root layout a `RelativeLayout` then using `android:layout_below` for your `Button`. Something like this should get you close

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@id/timer">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll" // id of your LinearLayout
        />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text=":" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It wasn't sure where you wanted your `TextView` so I left it alone.

Comment: I'd really like the whole 'Timer' module in its own layout so that it can be moved about and eventually packaged up into its own thing instead of having to be part of the larger application it is in. Is there a better way to do this if that is the case? I posted my entire XML file, the timer TextView is not going to be part of the timer module (I should probably get rid of that).

Comment: Do what I showed and tell me what is wrong with it and we will go from there. Take out what you don't want in there. You are confusing.

Comment: Ok, I used your code and this is what it is currently at http://i.imgur.com/lgz9pFQ.png

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I would like it to be two NumberPickers in the center of the screen with the start button below them (spanning the width of the two numberpickers).  I think the confusing part is the colon because I would really like the colon to be 'above' the two number pickers so that it is not spreading them apart and creating a space in between them.